# SQL convert unexpected result

Tags: sql, type-conversion

Please explain why
select convert(int,'1') = 1
but
select convert(int,
convert(varbinary(MAX),'1')) = 49

Answer (score 0):

Convert to varbinary without a style parameter defined translates each ASCII character in input string to a binary byte. That is why the input string '1' first gets mapped to the ASCII code 49, after which the outer convert returns the integer value 49.

Answer (score 0):

Because `convert(varbinary(MAX),'1')` is binary 0x31 which is integer  49.

Answer (score 0):

By using `varbinary` you are essentially converting the `ascii` representation of "1" to the actual binary digits which represent it.

You will get the same result using `select ascii('1')`.

In the same way select convert(varbinary(1),'A') = 0x41 which in `base 10` is 65, which is the `ascii` value for A